# Вращение объекта вокруг его точки Uniity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Сделал я в итоге вращение вокруг точки с помощью засовывания в пустой объект. В пустом объекте создал Box Collider и разместил его вот так:
[image: Как сделал]

Теперь центр пустого объекта находится посередине коллайдера и нужного объекта. Если вращать Пустой объект с помощью Move Tool в редакторе, получается то что мне нужно:
[image: То как нужно]

Но как теперь это сделать с помощью скрипта? Если еще учесть, что объект с rigitbody и физичен

Comment: Что вы сделали? Что значит "засовывание в пустой объект"? Что вращающийся коллайдер, в чем его смысл?

Comment: Ладно, единственное, что мне сейчас надо знать - это как с помощью c# вращать и передвигать объект по его собственным осям

Answer (score -1):

1. для начала сделай так что бы коллайдер был на кубе а не вне его. Второго коллайдера вне куба быть не должно.
2. Вращай вокруг нужной точки используя `RotateAround` (бери любую точку любого ребра куба. Ищи по слову `bounds` )

   `transform.RotateAround(Vector3.zero, Vector3.up, Time.deltaTime);` [тыц](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html)
3. Так же желательно заблочить повороты куба по всем осям в настройках ригитбоди. Что бы быть уверенным в том, что физика тебе не будет поворачивать твой куб неожиданно для тебя.

> Желательно поворачивать используя библиотеку LeanTween или аналог используя нелинейную функцию поворота для более "живой" анимации. Функции изменения переменных кажется нужно гуглить по ключевому слову `Ease` . но не уверен. Давно использовал.

С чем конкретно возникли проблемы? А то по вопросу непонятно.